# Passing arguments for function inside function

Tags: python, python-2.7

How does one determine the arguments for a function inside a function in python.

Consider an the following example:

```
def fun1():
    mysum = 0
    def fun2(arg):
        mysum += arg
    fun2(1)
    fun2(2)
    fun2(3)
    print mysum
```

This can be written as

```
def fun1():
    mysum = 0
    def fun2(mysum, arg):
        mysum += arg
    fun2(mysum, 1)
    fun2(mysum, 2)
    fun2(mysum, 3)
    print mysum
```

In the above case, sum can either be passed as argument or not. When does one determine if it should be passed as argument or not?

Comment: its a subjective question...

Comment: pls dont use variable names as `sum` or `count` etc as they are inbuilt functions

Comment: The first function is illegal in both Python-2 and -3, because the variable `mysum` in `fun2` is undefined (not declared as global). The second function is valid but useless, because all it simply increments the local variable. There is nothing _subjective_ there.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation. Do you want to modify a parameter variable or do you want your function to modify a closed variable. The latter may be less reusable, but in the end it is subjective.

In python3 you must use either global or nonlocal in order to modify any closed variables.

```
def fun1():
    sum = 0
    def fun2(arg):
        nonlocal sum
        sum += arg
    fun2(sum, 1)
    fun2(sum, 2)
    fun2(sum, 3)
    print sum
```